# Ambiguous Use of Subscript in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, subscript

I keep getting an error of "ambiguous use of subscript," in my Swift code. I don't know what's causing this error. It just randomly popped up. Here's my code:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MusicQuestions", ofType: "plist") {
    myQuestionsArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
}

var count:Int = 1
let currentQuestionDict = myQuestionsArray!.objectAtIndex(count)

if let button1Title = currentQuestionDict["choice1"] as? String {
    button1.setTitle("\(button1Title)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

if let button2Title = currentQuestionDict["choice2"] as? String {
    button2.setTitle("\(button2Title)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

if let button3Title = currentQuestionDict["choice3"] as? String {
    button3.setTitle("\(button3Title)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
if let button4Title = currentQuestionDict["choice4"] as? String {
    button4.setTitle("\(button4Title)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

if let question = currentQuestionDict["question"] as? String!{
    questionLabel.text = "\(question)"
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is **Subscripts**? If not, subscripts is a shortcut to access to a element of a collection. Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html)

By the way, could you post the type of your `currentQuestionDict` to understand the context.

Comment: The type? It's basically just an NSDictionary filled with strings.

Comment: Do not say what it is "basically". Every Swift variable has a declaration which gives it a specific type. _Show the declaration_ of `currentQuestionDict`. The entire answer to your question depends upon that declaration. To hide it is silly: it _is the answer_. Show it.

Comment: Isn't `let currentQuestionDict = myQuestionsArray!.objectAtIndex(count)` the declaration?

Comment: Good, I think that explains it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that you are using NSArray:

```
myQuestionsArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

This means that `myQuestionArray` is an NSArray. But an NSArray has no type information about its elements. Thus, when you get to this line:

```
let currentQuestionDict = myQuestionsArray!.objectAtIndex(count)
```

...Swift has no type information, and has to make `currentQuestionDict` an AnyObject. But you can't subscript an AnyObject, so expressions like `currentQuestionDict["choice1"]` cannot compile.

The solution is to use Swift types. If you know what `currentQuestionDict` really is, type it as that type. At the very least, since you seem to believe it is a dictionary, make it one; type it as `[NSObject:AnyObject]` (and more specific if possible). You can do this in several ways; one way is by casting when you create the variable:

```
let currentQuestionDict = 
    myQuestionsArray!.objectAtIndex(count) as! [NSObject:AnyObject]
```

In short, never use NSArray and NSDictionary if you can avoid it (and you can usually avoid it). If you receive one from Objective-C, type it as what it really is, so that Swift can work with it.

Comment: Excellent. Even more important, though, is to understand what I've said.

Comment: There is something I'm a bit confused about in your answer. You said that you can't subscript an AnyObject, but after you wrote ` myQuestionsArray!.objectAtIndex(count) as! [NSObject:AnyObject]`, the app ran successfully.

Comment: Because after that there is no AnyObject in this story. We cast it to an `[NSObject:AnyObject]`, aka a dictionary - and that is something you can subscript.

Comment: Oh. I think I understand what you did now.

Comment: You might want to read my book about Swift: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting

Comment: *NSArray has no type information about its elements.* <-- do you mean because `NSArray` is coming from Foundation, Swift doesn't know of it and so when passed into Swift. It will *automatically* be converted to `AnyObject`. As a result obviously we must be downcast `AnyObject` to `Array`?

Comment: @Honey No, I don't mean that.

Comment: Then what did you mean? :/

Comment: @Honey I meant exactly what I said, no more no less. If you have a different / related question, you know what to do. :)

Answer (score 7):

**["Key"]** has causing this error. New Swift update, you should use `objectForKey` to get your value. In you case just change the your code to ;

```
if let button1Title = currentQuestionDict.objectForKey("choice1") as? String {
    button1.setTitle("\(button1Title)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I used to solve the error:

```
    let cell:AddFriendTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFriendTableViewCell

    let itemSelection = items[indexPath.section] as! [AnyObject] //'items' is an array of NSMutableArrays, one array for each section

    cell.label.text = itemSelection[indexPath.row] as? String
```

Hope this helps!