# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' with NSArray & JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, subscript, ambiguous

I have looked through the similar topics in stackoverflow but none of those solutions seem to work for me.

I have an app that fetch video through youtube API . The following code is giving the error.

```
var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

// I am getting the error for the following line and it says "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'.

for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray {

    let videoObj = Video()
    videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
    videoObj.videoTitle = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as! String
    videoObj.videoDescription = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as! String
    videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.high.url") as! String


    arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)

}
```

I have also a class called Video where I define the Id, Title and etc... The above code refers here.

```
class Video: NSObject {

    var videoId:String = ""
    var videoTitle:String = ""
    var videoDescription:String = ""
    var videoThumbnailUrl:String = ""

}
```

I have tried to solve it by checking the link/suggestions below but it didn't work for me. I cannot seem to find the missing part.

[Ambiguous Use of Subscript in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642059/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-in-swift)

Comment: What is the `JSON` object? Show us how you created that.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `JSON` variable please?

Comment: Thanks Rob and George for your attention on this case. I have the following lines for your reference. I couldn't post the full code as a comment. I hope this helps. 

class VideoModal: NSObject {
    
    var videoArray = [Video]()
                
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    
                    var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is almost certainly that your `JSON` is defined as a type that could be an array or a dictionary. With Xcode 7.1 ambiguity enforcement was levelled up, so you need to explicitly cast it to something that can be subscripted by a string. This should sort you nicely:

```
for video in (JSON as! NSDictionary)["items"] as! NSArray
```

Comment: I was able to sort out the problem with your suggestion. It is working fine. Many thanks for your help!