# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value // (JSON as! NSDictionary)["items"]

Tags: ios, json, swift

I previously had problem with the JSON data but found a solution to it as suggested by **alexcurylo** in the link down below;

[Ambiguous use of 'subscript' with NSArray & JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755374/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-with-nsarray-json)

It was working fine for a while but now it is returning **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** on the following line: **for video in (JSON as! NSDictionary)["items"] as! NSArray {**. Any suggestion on this? I thought that might be related to thumbnails not having maxres but changing it default or high didn't work either.

```
    let API_KEY = "BrowserKey"


    let UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID = "playlistID"


    var videoArray = [Video]()


    var delegate: VideoModelDelegate?


    func getFeedVideos() {

//Fetch the videos dynamically through the Youtube DATA API
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", parameters: ["part":"snippet", "playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in


if let JSON = response.result.value {

    var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()


    for video in (JSON as! NSDictionary)["items"] as! NSArray {


        // create video objects off of the JSON response

        let videoObj = Video()
        videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
        videoObj.videoTitle = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as! String
        videoObj.videoDescription = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as! String
        videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.default.url") as! String


        arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)

    }

    //when all the video objects constructed, assign the array to the VideoModel property
    self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos

    //Notify the delegate that the data is ready

    if self.delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.dataReady()
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Either (a) the `JSON` was not a dictionary; (b) it couldn't find anything with the key `items`; or (c) it did find something, but it wasn't an array. You have to test for these situations, one by one, (e.g. with `guard`) and see which doesn't hold.

Comment: I just made [this](https://github.com/romainmenke/Jenerator) for exactly these kind of issues. It takes a lot of time to map JSON responses and this cli will create a swift model from a JSON for you. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you don't abuse the force unwrap operator (`!`) like this.

In expression `(JSON as! NSDictionary)["items"] as! NSArray`:

1. You are forcefully casting `JSON` to `NSDictionary`. If `JSON` isn't an `NSDictionary` or a subclass of it, this forced cast will fail and cause a crash.
2. You are subscripting to get the value for the key `"items"`. This could return `nil`, if there's no mapping for `"items"`
3. You are forcefully casting that value to `NSArray`. If the value is `nil`, this will crash. If the value isn't an `NSArray` or one of its subclasses, this will crash.

The `!` should be using sparingly. It creates an assertion that whatever it's unwrapping/casting is valid. As there's no "backup" plan, such as in the case of and `if let / else` statement, the program crashes. **This is an intentional design choice**, to prevent the program from continueing to execute in an inconcistent, unforeseen state.

You should use `if let` and `guard` to safely handle this data, and react to errors.

Comment: Forcing it NSDictionary was part of the problem, so I have changed it to -->> for video in (JSON["items"] as? NSArray)! --<<. I have also checked if the videoId, thumbnails and other details are available or not. Thanks!

Comment: What was the right answer... I am having the same problem